# Retrieve Data from Firebase Database and populate Listview

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-arrayadapter

I am trying to retrieve data from Firebase database using Array adapter for populating list view but no success ? How can it be done?

This is my ArrayAdapter class.

```
public class ModelListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Model> {
    ArrayList<Model> mode = new ArrayList<Model>();
    private Query mRef;
    private Class<Model> mModelClass;
    private int mLayout;
    private Context context;
    private List<Model> mModels;
    private Activity activity;


    public ModelListAdapter(Activity activity, int mLayout ,Class<Model> mModelClass, Query mRef) {
        super(activity,mLayout,mModelClass,mRef);
        this.mRef = mRef;
        this.mModelClass = mModelClass;
        this.mLayout = mLayout;
        mInflater = activity.getLayoutInflater();
    }
```

This is MainActivity class.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String FIREBASE_URL = "https://XYZ.firebaseio.com/";
    private ModelListAdapter adapter;
    private ListView listView;
    private FirebaseApp app;
    private Firebase ref;
    private FirebaseDatabase database;
    private FirebaseStorage storage;

    private DatabaseReference databaseRef;
    private StorageReference storageRef;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.logo);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.gradient));
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Firebase.setAndroidContext(this);

        app = FirebaseApp.getInstance();
        database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance(app);
        storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance(app);

        databaseRef = database.getReference(FIREBASE_URL);
        ref = new Firebase(FIREBASE_URL);

        adapter = new ModelListAdapter(this,Model.class,R.layout.list_item,ref);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        adapter.registerDataSetObserver(new DataSetObserver() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged() {
                super.onChanged();
            }
        });

        databaseRef.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                Model model = dataSnapshot.getValue(Model.class);
                adapter.mode.add(model);

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });

    }
}
```

**I am getting Error**:

> no suitable constructor found  for ArrayAdapter(Activity,int, class<>,Query)
>   (Argument mismatch; Class<> cannot be int)

Comment: See https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/download-files. Or https://gist.github.com/puf/f49a1b07e92952b44f2dc36d9af04e3c. If you're having trouble getting your code to work, post the [minimum code that reproduces where you're stuck](;http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcv). This allows us to see where you might be going wrong.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen this is the code where I get stuck,please help

Comment: `ArrayAdapter` has no constructor that takes those arguments. See https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#pubctors. You seem to be in over your head a bit here. For an easier time, you might want to consider basing your work on the adapters in FirebaseUI:  https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/tree/master/database